# cross domain file upload using jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cross-domain, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery file upload by Blueimp, and I need to do cross domain file upload(from localhost:8008 to localhost:8000)

But in the initial stage I didn't get the response even, and I got this error:
[XMLHttpRequest cannot load](http://examples.com:8000/multi/multi_uploader_details/). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [Origin](http://examples.com:8008) is therefore not allowed access.

And the jQuery is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'http://examples.com/multi/multi/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        fileInput: $('#fileupload'),
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        multipart: true,
        autoUpload: true,

        done: function (e, data) {
             $.each(data.files, function (index, file) { 
                debugger;
              console.log(file); 
              $.support.cors = true; 
              $.post('examples.com/multi/multi_uploader_details/', 'file_name='+file) 
              .success(function(resp){ 
                  console.log(resp); 
                  if(resp.code == 0){ 
                      $("#file_db_id").val(resp.data.identifier); 
                  } 
                  else{ 
                      alert(resp.data); 
                  } 
              }) 
              .fail(function(){ 
                  alert("error"); 
              }); 
        
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: You can use a ful implementation of CORS: a detailled tutorial can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) it's expected to be more modern. But do not expect it to work on old browsers: IE<=7, Opera<12, or Firefox<3.5

Comment: Is there a crossDomain attribute in the extension like there is in .ajax()in [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). if so, try to set it to true.